# aws-sdk node equivalent of boto3 credentials python calls

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, aws-sdk, aws-elasticsearch

I have inherited a python lambda which I need to convert to node js. I am a bit stuck with the code that handles authentication and so I am wondering what the JS equivalent would be for the python code below:

```py
import boto3
import json
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

region = "eu-west-2"
service = "es"

credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

r = requests.get(url, auth=awsauth)
```

Here is my work in progress at what seem to be relevant calls using the javascript `aws-sdk`:

```js
import AWS from "aws-sdk"

const region = "eu-west-2"
const service = "es"

const credentials = AWS.Credentials().get()

const response = await fetch(url, {
  headers: { Authorization: credentials },
  credentials: "include"
})
```

I know the python code works, so I just need to convert it to JS. As you can see I'm not really sure what to do with `credentials` once I have it or what the equivalent of `auth=awsauth` would be within the `fetch` call. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try the example from here https://github.com/mhart/aws4/blob/master/example.js#L28. It has details on how you can sign.

Comment: @Redtama have you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: @MalcolmXYZ no I moved on from the project that required this so never found a good solution.

Comment: @Redtama In my case someone else had a nifty tool that got temporary credentials through aws sts https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sts/ I hope you can get it to work like that. Otherwise check nike gimme-aws-creds that might give you the hints you need.